# Unable to access camunda cockpit page

Tags: java, spring-boot, camunda

I'm using spring boot camunda to build some wf.

All my process works fine, but I cannot access to camunda cockpit interface.

I added the url to `WebConfig.java` to disable auth by `.antMatchers("/camunda/app/**").permitAll()`.

Now I have 200 OK but a white page and the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:8083/camunda/app/admin/default/setup/
net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 200
```

Any ideas why this may happen and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a default user with configuration like below :

```
camunda:
    bpm:
        admin-user:
            id: demo
            password: 1234
            firstName: Default
```

If you dont create user with config, camunda will forward you a setup page to create a user.

Could you try
http://localhost:yourport/camunda/app/cockpit/default/#/login

If you have context path use below
http://localhost:yourport/yourContextPath/camunda/app/cockpit/default/#/login

Answer (score 0):

Can you try hitting "http://localhost:8080"
If context path provided then, "http://localhost:8080/${contextPath}", this should direct you to cockpit web UI.